# Domain mapping subdirectory to external domain

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, wordpress, directory

I'm running a Wordpress multisite install where the blogs are created in subdirectories - e.g. www.mydomain.com/blog1, www.mydomain.com/blog2

I need to clarify what I think is and isn't possible with domain mapping so that clients can use their own domain (and therefore improve their SEO) for the blog.

What I want in an ideal world is for www.clientdomain.com/blog to serve the respective Wordpress blog (e.g. www.mydomain.com/blog6) BUT as far as the user is concerned, they are looking at www.clientdomain.com/blog.

I know this is possible with subdomain mapping (e.g. I can serve www.mydomain.com/blog6 as blog.clientdomain.com) but is there any solution for making a subdirectory of one domain serve a website on another domain?

I don't think this is possible without using 301 redirects in .htaccess but just need someone to confirm this for me.

In summary, I believe my options are:

1. User types www.clientdomain.com/blog and browser loads www.mydomain.com/blog6 (address bar also shows www.mydomain.com/blog6) using .htaccess redirect 301.
2. User types blog.clientdomain.com and browser loads www.mydomain.com/blog6 (address bar remains blog.clientdomain.com) using domain mapping DNS.

For more information, hosting for wordpress multisite and client website is completely different and client website will have a "normal" site plus email in addition to their blog.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You need need to add an vserver with the document root set to the root of the blog (say for example `/var/www/blog6`) and the vserver name to `blog.clientdomain.com`. That should do what you want.

---

### Edit

What you are really looking for is a [reverse proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html). With reverse Proxying you can let the server resolve a path (for example `/blog`) from another server.

```
+--------+   Request   +--------------------+   Request    +--------------------+
| Client |-----------> | Server domain1.com |------------->| Server domain2.com |
+--------+    /blog    +--------------------+   /blog6     +--------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I need the client domain URL to be clientdomain.com/blog rather than blog.clientdomain.com. I don't think there's any way to map a subdirectory onto a domain without doing a 301 redirect?

Comment: Sure there is. It's called reverse proxy. Let me revise my post.

Comment: Now I have added new info

Comment: why this answer is not accepted, or no-one upvoted?